# Drupal 6 on browser close automatic logout by user role

Tags: session, drupal-6, logout

Is there any module or possibility to automatically logout user filtered by role when browser is closed?

The only thing I found was ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0); in settings.php, but this is not helpful, because it is for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the windows beforeunload event, and make an ajax call to user/logout, which will log out the user.

To add the role testing element, you could copy the user/logout page callback function and add your own version of user_logout page callback function that checks the role.  For example "user_logout_by_role"

In your custom module, add hook_menu

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {

  $items['user/logout_by_role'] = array(
    'title' => 'Log out',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_user_logout_by_role',
    'weight' => 10,
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
  );


  return $items;
}
```

then, copy the user logout function and add some code to check role

```
function mymodule_user_logout_by_role() {
  global $user;

  if (in_array('editor', $user->roles)) {

    watchdog('user', 'Session closed for %name.', array('%name' => $user->name));

    module_invoke_all('user_logout', $user);

    // Destroy the current session, and reset $user to the anonymous user.
    session_destroy();

  }


  die();
}
```

Here's some other helpful tips for the [beforeunload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614491/how-to-activate-a-function-before-user-close-browser-tab).